# How can I solve DEGREES in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, degrees

When I run the query below with PHP I get the following error: 
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DEGREES'

```
public function getNearbyActivities($lat,$lng)
    {
        $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT id,name,lat,lng, 
                ROUND(
                        111.045 * 
                        DEGREES(
                            ACOS(
                                COS(
                                    RADIANS($lat)
                                )
                                * COS(
                                    RADIANS(lat)
                                )
                                * COS(
                                    RADIANS(lng)
                                    - (
                                        RADIANS($lng)
                                    )
                                    + SIN(
                                        RADIANS($lat)
                                    )
                                    * SIN(
                                        RADIANS(lat)
                                    )
                                )
                            ),2)
                AS distance_in_km FROM activities
            ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC") 
            or die($this->conn->error);
        $stores = array();
        while ($activities = $result->fetch_assoc())
            $stores[] = $activities;
        return $stores;
    }
```

Comment: Fix the number of parameter .... simples

Comment: And the issue is in MySQL not PHP

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis to end your DEGREES function.

Comment: where can you help me......

Comment: I think you are only missing ONE `)` but basically match your braces

Comment: ya got it....solved thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `)` see below

```
    $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT id,name,lat,lng, 
            ROUND(
                    111.045 * 
                    DEGREES(
                        ACOS(
                            COS(
                                RADIANS($lat)
                                )

                                * COS(
                                    RADIANS(lat)
                                )
                                * COS(
                                    RADIANS(lng) - (RADIANS($lng)
                                )
                                + SIN(
                                    RADIANS($lat)
                                )
                                * SIN(
                                    RADIANS(lat)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )       // <- missing brace
                ,2)
            AS distance_in_km FROM activities
        ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC")
```